# no debug output

Tags: debugging

I'm working on an extension for expresso store and I want to output some variables, using print_r or echo but nothing is outputted on the front-end.

I'm logged in as admin, I have template debugging on, I have php enabled for the template I'm looking (and yes the template is calling the extension)

any help?

thanks
Francesco

EE 2.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put in die(); or exit(); after the stuff you'd like to inspect.
otherwise your extension will keep running and you may not see the output.

Comment: this, especially with Expresso which will throw redirects in there, (product added -> redirect to cart), checkout button on cart == submit cart form -> redirect to checkout, ect... Another option is to dump your output to a (log) file so you don't have to `die` the code.

Comment: Wonderfull! it works! So is it alwais needed to do like that?

Comment: Frequently, yes. Especially if you want to see your raw data before and after you've manipulate it. As mentioned you can log it to a file if you want to do comparisons after you've made code adjustments.